# Data transfer speed in between two routers

Tags: router, speed

I have two routers (bridged) setup at home to cover both ends of the house. The two routers is connected through power line. While the speed is acceptable for general use (browsing, emailing etc) but I experience significant lag while streaming video from a hard drive connected to one router to a TV connected to the other router.

DCHP is handled by the router to which the hard drive is attached.

My question: if I connect the hard drive to the same router that the TV connect to, will the data transfer still be routed to the other router first (given that router serve as DHCP) before it gets to the TV. Or will the data transfer go directly between hard drive to the TV?

I know I can just experiment with it ... but I would like to know what theoretically will happen.

I hope my question does make sense. Thank you.

EDIT: More information about the setup

Modem: 192.168.1.2

Router 1: 192.168.1.1
(this router handles the DHCP and to which a hard drive is connected)
This functions also as an access point
This router is connected through one of its LAN port to one of Modem's LAN port (bridge)

Router 2: 192.168.1.3
This router is connected through one of its LAN port to the powerline adaptor which on the other end is connected to Modem's LAN port.
This functions as an access point as well
The TV is connected to this router.

Comment: Can you post routing tables of the two routers, and give us enough information to determine what IP networks are in use and which network each device is intended to be on in the target configuration?

Comment: Hi @Slartibartfast thank you for your response. I have updated my question with more information. Do you need more info? Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both the routers are in the same IP network, there is no routing between the devices, the traffic is directly switched on Layer 2 using MAC addresses.

DHCP server location doesn't affect the flow of traffic.

Comment: hi Tero, are you saying that I will get better speed if I attach the hard drive the the same router as the TV because data does not need to  travel through the powerline? Cheers.

Comment: Yes, that is what my answer implies.